# How can I enter Fastboot or Recovery mode on the eSTAR X35?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

My eSTAR X35 is stuck in a bootloop and I can't reach fastboot mode.  How can I get there or into Recovery mode?

Comment: Also see our [fastboot tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) :)

Answer (score 0):

Press the volume down and power button at the same time. If that does not work try pressing all three buttons at once (power, volume up, and volume down)